# Chart controls for MFC application?

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

I would like to have some suggestions about which third-part controls can we use in our Visual C++ MFC application?

Comment: As Gigasoft's founder, readers searching mfc charting please see [Gigasoft's MFC Charting](http://www.gigasoft.com) for a demo or eval providing a quick way to investigate the features and behaviors. Direct2D, Direct3D, GdiPlus, and Gdi rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've deployed [IOComp](http://iocomp.com/)'s Plot Pack in both ActiveX and .Net flavors with great success.  Great API, incredibly flexible, provides a toolbar that lets users pan/zoom/customize.  It's solid, has a long track record, relatively inexpensive, and is very fast.

(I'm not affiliated, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Xtreme Toolkit Pro controls
http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/

Answer (score 1):

The IOComp package  (http://iocomp.com/ ) looks great, but does seem quite expensive to me at around $850 for a developer license

The TeeChart package ( http://www.steema.com ) looks comparable at a smaller prices of $450.  They have a free 50 day evaluation license

There are a couple of *free* chart controls at codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CBarChart.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/High-speedCharting.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/graph2d.aspx  This one I have used.  The integration procedure is awkward, but it does the job.

FarPoint and codejock, AFAIK, do not have chart controls.

Answer (score 1):

We have used the ActiveX version of TeeChart (http://www.steema.com/), which works nicely and comes with many MFC examples. It's ActiveX though, that may or may not be a problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness [Scientific charting control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/xgraph.aspx). I used it some time ago and it was pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Best chart for MFC I have seen, modern, stable and very well written

http://www.codejock.com/products/chart/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying, there's FarPoint Spread:

http://www.componentsource.com/selec/products/farpoint-spread/summary.html