# High speed graphing control for .NET (or MFC)?

Tags: c#, .net, mfc, controls, graph

I need to write a digital oscilloscope type application.  There are many great static graphing controls out there, but I need something that can graph 16 traces processing 4000 samples per second.

Is anyone aware of a high speed graphing control for .NET?  I'll even take MFC since that can be wrapped into a .NET control.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

How about ZedGraph? They mention realtime applications specifically here:

http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data

They claim at least ~20 samples per second.

At 4000 samples per second I don't think you're going to want to plot all the points in real time since you're going to make it all the way across the screen in 0.25 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

[DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219737(VS.85).aspx) used to have .NET bindings (not sure about current version). It includes support for high-performance 2D and 3D graphics. If anything on Windows can meet your requirements, it will be DirectX.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking DirectX for performance reasons.  I just don't want to have to write my own control if I can use someone else's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [GraphViz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz)? I've seen it used in oscilloscope applications, but I'm not positive it will handle the speed you're looking for. GraphViz doesn't take a 'live feed' of instructions like some of the GDI+ controls I've seen.

There are some [.NET wrappers](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph) [for it](http://quickgraph.tigris.org/source/browse/quickgraph/trunk/src/).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [QCRTGraph](http://www.quinn-curtis.com/QCRTGraphProdPage.htm) control. You can also look at this [CodeGuru project](http://www.codeguru.com/article.php/c2223/).

Though, honestly, with your requirements you might be better off doing your own C++ implementation of it. With only 0.25ms per sample, locking and updating the buffer of any third party control is too expensive for you to afford.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Visual Numerics](http://www.vni.com).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [**Universal Real-Time Software Oscilloscope GUI DLL Library**](http://www.oscilloscope-lib.com/).  It's only a DLL, but is capable of high performance.  Take a look at the example applications.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78061/chart-controls-for-mfc-application#78632).  I highly recommend [IOComp](http://iocomp.com) for both MFC (ActiveX) and .Net. Very fast and stable.

http://opcactivex.com/Related_Products___Development/Development_Tools/Plot_Pack/screen_iocomp_plotpack.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a National Instruments solution for .NET. National Instruments always had a leading position in data acquisition and instrument control. They have a library for charting/graphing in .NET however it is commercial.

Comment: I'll second the NI Measurement Studio.  I've plotted 1000 points/sec with NI Measurement Studio's chart control.  Also, this test was done on a laptop with a very lousy video card.  AFAIK, Measurement Studio is using OpenGL internally.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics rednereing (points and lines on a widget) is fairly simple - you could do this with raw Win32 a la Petzold.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Steema Teechart (http://www.steema.com/teechart/net). I must add that I do not have any hands-on expericience with very high speed processing.